# What tag to use to hide content in JSF

Tags: jsf, jstl

When I want to hide some content in JSF, what tag is made for this purpose? There are several tags that can do the job:

```
<f:subview rendered="#{...condition...}" />
```

and

```
<c:when test="#{...conditon...}" />
```

Which is the right one to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ui:remove>
```

Look here: http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/facelets/10-TagReference/facelets-ui-remove.html

UPDATE

If you want to conditionally hide some content, you can use

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{...condition...}">
```

It renders as `<span>`, you can also add attribute `layout="block"`

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{...condition...}" layout="block">
```

to render it as `<div>`.

Comment: He want to **conditionally** hide content.

Comment: and is there an element that does not render any html && does have semantics of being a container for other elements?

Comment: You could try `<ui:fragment>`. It does not support `rendered` attribute but... it works.

Answer (score 2):

in JSF, using `rendered` is the best approach.

Using JSTL tags like `<c:when>`, is not recommended at all, and even break some functunality of JSF like ViewScope annotation. Always try to use JSF tags (like `ui:repeat` instead of `c:forEach`)

Comment: thanks for answering, and what tag should I use when I'm just embracing some html code which naturally doesn't have rendered attribute?